# Append Playa field via Safecracker

Tags: expressionengine, safecracker

I'm building an artist directory and using Pixel & Tonic's Playa to manage each member's "fans."

In each user's profile, there is a multi-select Playa field that displays all of the members that user has "fanned" (similar to "like" on Facebook).

What I'd like to do is have a "link" that's actually a safecracker submission that will add a member's name to the user's Playa field.

Essentially, it will be a form with hidden fields for the User's ID and the screen name of the member whose page is being viewed. I want to append the screen name to the user's existing Playa field entries.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a custom plugin to do this, so you can perform a custom SQL insert.

Not sure if you're familar with writing plugins, but you can get started by creating one via [pkg.io](http://pkg.io/), and then adding this function to the resulting file. Then you can create a link to a template where you place your new tag, and perhaps pass the ids for the member and the new fan via segments:

```
{exp:my_plugin:add_fan member_id="{segment_3}" fan_id="{segment_4}"}
```

This function makes the (perhaps mistaken) assumption that you're storing your members in channels (I assume so, because you're using a Playa field), and that you have access in your templates to the entry_id of both the member and fan. If not, you may need to perform some more queries to find the entry_id of each. It also calls your Playa field `field_id_10` ... you'll need to replace `10` with the proper field_id of your Playa field.

```
function add_fan()
{
    $this->EE =& get_instance();

    $member_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('member_id');
    $fan_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('fan_id');

    $data = array(
        'parent_entry_id' => $member_id,
        'child_entry_id' => $fan_id,
        'parent_field_id' => 10
    );

    $this->EE->db->query(
        $this->EE->db->insert_string('exp_playa_relationships', $data)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Safecracker too, and create hidden field for the Playa:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_playa_field_name[selections][]" />
```

You must use the Playa field name here (not the field_id).

Then you can submit your Safecracker form in ajax.